# How to reference and parse Json VBA Ms Access

Tags: json, vba, ms-access

I want to be helped to get the Arrays of Json into my table in Ms Access, how do I reference the arrays.

I have been having problems with arrays for sometime now that is why I need this sorted once and for all

```
With rs
    .AddNew
    ![id] = item("id")
    ![riority] = item("urgent")
    ![Status] = item("Closed")
    .Update
End With

{
  "Tickets": [
    {
      "id": 866883,
      "type": "problem",
      "priority": "urgent",
      "status": "closed",
      "follower_ids": [
        7967649388,
        7967864608,
        365003995267,
        7897694567,
        7897776387,
        7899032227,
        7969040908,
        7898078107
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want someone to show me how to reference values from arrays in Ms access VBA

Comment: How do I get 7967649388 which is in the Array that is where my question is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference arrays in VBA JSON (using dictionary), you need to specify which element in the array you want:

Using your example:

`item(1)("id")` will equal `866883` and `item(1)("status")` will equal `closed`. To reference the next item, use `item(2)("id")`